# MySQL Backup (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql

What are the possible reasons why i can't backup my DB using `MYSQLDUMP`?
In my localhost, i can backup the db but when I use the db in my hosting, there seems to be a problem. Is it possible that my hosting can't backup db? Btw, im using cloudbees in my database. I'm 100% sure that I change all the username, password and the name of the db when using my hosting `MySQL`. Actually it creates the `.sql` file but it is empty.

```
String executeCmd = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u " + username
                    + " -p" + password + " somedbname" + " -r "
                    + "C:/tech-report-db/backup"
                    + c.getTimeInMillis() + c.getWeekYear() + ".sql";
            try {

                Process runtimeProcess;

                runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);

                int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

                if (processComplete == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
                }
```

---

### it returns the error "Could not create the backup"

---

Comment: Where are you running this? Locally or on CloudBees?

Comment: Don't do this. MySQL already has a facility for scheduled backups. Use it. You don't need to write Java code for this purpose.

Comment: I tried both. It works locally but not in cloudbees.. Same code. different username dbname and password

Comment: @EJP can you give me a link about that scheduled backups?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Sorry for incomplete question. I'm using a remote mysql so i need to include the hostip and the port

before:

```
String executeCmd = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u " + username
                    + " -p" + password + " somedbname" + " -r "
                    + "C:/tech-report-db/backup"
                    + c.getTimeInMillis() + c.getWeekYear() + ".sql";
```

now:

```
String executeCmd = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -P "+port+ " -h "+hostIP+ " -u " + username
                    + " -p" + password + " somedbname" + " -r "
                    + "C:/tech-report-db/backup"
                    + c.getTimeInMillis() + c.getWeekYear() + ".sql";
```